# Causal Impact (Python) Extract Absolute Effects and Credible Intervals from Summary

Tags: python, pandas, causal-inference

I am trying to extract the results from the Causal Impact python package.

I have run the causal impact model using CausalImpact() and seen the output table using .summary().

I would like to extract the Absolute and Cumulative Absolute Effect and the corresponding credible intervals from .summary(). However .summary() returns a 'NoneType' and I haven't been able to determine how to extract these values.

Any help is appreciated!

I have tried using str() and parsing through other methods such as .inference but have been unable to find the values that are used in .summary() and .summary('report').